# What is difference between holder.getAdapterPosition() and position attribute from constructor in onBindViewHolder()

Tags: java, android

Here is my code -

```
public void onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder holder, int position) {

        //1. details obj = list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        //2. details obj = list.get(position);

        holder.position = position;
    }
```

I am getting a warning

> Do not treat position as fixed; only use immediately and call
>   holder.getAdapterPosition() to look it up later RecyclerView will not
>   call onBindViewHolder again when the position of the item changes in
>   the data set unless the item itself is invalidated or the new position
>   cannot be determined.  For this reason, you should only use the
>   position parameter while acquiring the related data item inside this
>   method, and should not keep a copy of it.  If you need the position of
>   an item later on (e.g. in a click listener), use getAdapterPosition()
>   which will have the updated adapter position later.

So i am confused from 1 and 2 which should i prefer and why? As it says getAdapterPosition() gives updated position and i am getting values from list based on position.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The warning you get is not about using `position` or `getAdapterPosition()`. It is about saving the position:

```
holder.position = position;
```

You don't need to save the position in your holder, because its position can change and you can always get its position by calling `holder.getAdapterPosition()`;

From the docs:

> Note that unlike ListView, RecyclerView will not call this method
>   again if the position of the item changes in the data set unless the
>   item itself is invalidated or the new position cannot be determined.
>   For this reason, you should only use the position parameter while
>   acquiring the related data item inside this method and should not keep
>   a copy of it. If you need the position of an item later on (e.g. in a
>   click listener), use getAdapterPosition() which will have the updated
>   adapter position.

**About which to use:**

Both should return the same result if called inside the `onBindViewHolder` method. I would recommend using `position` because it is easiest and safest.